# How to make a Python function run concurrently or sequentially depending on the number of function calls and function arguments?

Tags: python, concurrency, python-asyncio

I have the following sample function:

```
def set_value(thing, set_quantity):
    set_function(thing, set_quantity) #sets "thing" to the desired quantity 
    read_value = read_function(thing) #reads quantity of "thing"
    if read_value != set_quantity:
        raise Exception('Values are not equal')
```

I then have some test cases (they're Robot Framework test cases but I don't think that really matters for the question I have) that look something like this:

```
#test case 1
set_value('Bag_A', 5)

#Test case 2
set_value('Bag_B', 3)

#Test case 3
set_value('Bag_A', 2)
set_value('Bag_B', 8)
set_value('Purse_A',4)
```

This is the desired behavior I want:

For Test Case 1, `set_value()` is called once and is executed right after the function call.

Test Case 2 is similar to #1 and its behavior should be the same.

For Test Case 3, we have 3 items: Bag_A, Bag_B, and Purse_A. Bag_A and Bag_B each call `set_value()`, but I want them to run concurrently. This is because they're both "Bags" (regardless of the _A or _B assignation), so I want the function to recognize that they are both "Bags" and should be run concurrently. Once those are executed and finished, then I want the Purse_A function call to `set_value()` to be executed (since "Purse" is not in the same category as "Bag").

The object type ("bag", "purse", etc) can be anything, so I'm not expecting a particular value from a small amount of pre-defined possibilities.
How would I go about doing this? By the way, I cannot change anything in the way the Test Cases are written.

I tried looking into the asyncio module since you're able to run things concurrently using tasks, but the things is I don't understand how to get `set_function()` to know how many tasks there will be since it all depends on any future functions calls which depends on each test case.

Comment: Your last paragraph is confusing to me.  You talk about `set_function` but there is no previous mention of this function, and nothing of that name in the code.  You seem to be saying that you want to write a function that can see into the future ("depends on future function calls").  I have never heard of a Python package for that :-).  Can you clarify your requirement?

Comment: As stated in the previous comment: there is no way a function can  "preview the future"  and decide if it should run immediately, or wait to see if there are calls to run in parallel.
There are lots of ways, however, of triggering an async execution, and add more tasks to that workflow if in subsequent calls tasks on the same group are required. 
All of these will require a specialized way to check the results (be it by calling a returned value `.result()` method, or awaiting on the execution).

Comment: So, if you want a meaningful answer, you have to provide a working example of the code which _calls_  the "magic" function, so that it can be adapted in an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, if you want your program to do some thing, you just have to write your own code to do the thing:

```py
thread_pool = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(...)

def do_one(task):
    ...

def do_something_with(result):
    ...

def do_concurrently(tasks):
    global thread_pool
    futures = []
    for task in tasks:
        futures.append(thread_pool.submit(do_one, task))
    for future in futures:
        result = future.result()
        do_something_with(result)

def do_sequentially(tasks):
    for task in tasks:
        result = do_one(task)
        do_something_with(result)

def task_performer(...):
    tasks = ...construct list of tasks...
    if ...tasks should be performed concurrently...:
        do_concurrently(tasks)
    else:
        do_sequentially(tasks)
```

Very procedural. I can't help it, I'm an old-fart. Maybe there's some more modern, stylish way to do it, but you get the idea, right?